# POST ARRAY Request with java in okhttp

Tags: java, android, android-studio, okhttp

I need to send an array like this(got it from backend dev) to the server using okhttp java, any ideas?
It will be better to get some literature about it

```
[answers] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [answer_id] => 4648
                [duration_time_question] => 0
                [text_open_answer] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [answer_id] => 4650
                [duration_time_question] => 0
                [text_open_answer] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [answer_id] => 4667
                [duration_time_question] => 1
                [text_open_answer] => 
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [answer_id] => 4652
                [duration_time_question] => 1
                [text_open_answer] => 
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [answer_id] => 4678
                [duration_time_question] => 0
                [text_open_answer] => 
            )
```

I have already tried many variants to to send an array, but none work(
This code i use in the needed part

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.newCall(new DoRequest().Post(dictionary, getIntent().getExtras().getString("url"), array))
                    .enqueue(new Callback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("Failed");

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                            String temp = response.body().string();

                            System.out.println("Success " + temp);

                        }


                    });
```

And this is supported class for requests. On the one hand it works when i send data at key-value form but on the other it doesnt send my arrays via for.

```
public Request Post(Dictionary<String, String> dictionary, String url, Dictionary<String, String> data) {
    RequestBody formBody = null;
    Dictionary<String, String> array = new Hashtable<>();


           for (int i = 0; i < array.size() / 3; i++) {
                formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("answers["+i+"]", array.get("answer_id"))
                        .add("answers["+i+"]", array.get("duration_time_question"))
                        .add("answers["+i+"]", array.get("text_open_answer"))
                        .build();
            }


            break;

    }
    return new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody).build();
}
```

Comment: So you want to send that exact syntax, thus json is not applicable, right?

Comment: is that only String?just send it normally

Comment: @NickCardoso yp, u r right, it's not json